# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio Cannot debug

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Just upgraded to the RC2 version of Node.js tools and I can no longer stop at a breakpoint. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Environment: Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio Pro 2013

Project settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up contacting the Visual Studio Node.js Tools team about this. They reached back out to me and after testing together via a Skype session they ultimately found the bug.

See the codexplex issue: http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/workitem/1862

They recently moved to GitHub. See the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/66